# Getting wrong IP address through AJAX but correct in direct PHP api

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have the following PHP code to get Client IP address:

```
<?php

function getRealIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
echo json_encode(array('ip'=>getRealIpAddr()));

?>
```

When I run this API directly or through Postman, I get the correct IP address i.e. my own IP address.

My AJAX Code:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        var getresponse = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                        ipaddr = getresponse.ip;
                        console.log(ipaddr);
                  }  
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "ipapi.php", true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send();
```

But when I call this api through AJAX in my HTML, I get incorrect IP address. The resultant IP address that I get in ajax is of my server (Hostgator server) and not my own IP address.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And which case is being hit in that function? Guessing it differs across the two requests you've described.

Comment: Have you tried to use the full URL in the request, rather than the relative part?

Comment: Oh wow. It worked on using the full URL in request. Thanks Tom. But I want to understand what made the difference in full url request and the other way that lead to changes in resultant IP address?

Comment: Well using the relative path means it accesses the PHP file from the server directly thus making the request come from the server internally rather than the full URL making it an external request

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP example, you are getting the `HTTP_CLIENT_IP` with the function `getRealIpAddr()`, but in your ajax call you are only using the `ipapi.php` as URL.

You have to enter the full URL on this call like :

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.myAwesomeURL.com/getIpApi", true);
```

And on this `GET /getIpApi` server road must return the result of your function `getRealIpAddr()`, then you gonna be able to use it in your front-end app.